# How can I configure the default audio output in VLC player?

Tags: audio, video, hdmi, raspberry-pi, vlc-media-player

I'm running VLC Player on a raspberry pi 4, connected to my TV via HDMI, the TV is the only output device that's connected to the pi. I'm not concerned with music at the moment, I just want the default audio out for video fixed, although, I will only be using this pi with my TV, so I ideally want all audio routed though HDMI.

When I select the HDMI output manually from the drop-menu in VLC Player it works as expected, but every time I start the player I have to manually set it to the HDMI output, not only that, if I queue up multiple videos in a playlist and select the HDMI output the first video plays fine, but then the audio switches back to the headphone output once the next video starts. It's very frustrating.
So every time I want to watch an episode of anything I have to manually set the audio output to HDMI.

I've tried adjusting the settings with no luck, perhaps I'm setting the wrong one and then it's defaulting to the headphone socket or something.
This is the setting I've used most recently:
[image: VLC Player audio settings]

I've tried with both HDMI 0 and HDMI 1 with no success.
When I run `modetest -c` I get the following output:

```
trying to open device 'i915'...failed                                                                                      
trying to open device 'amdgpu'...failed                                                                                    
trying to open device 'radeon'...failed                                                                                    
trying to open device 'nouveau'...failed                                                                                   
trying to open device 'vmwgfx'...failed                                                                                    
trying to open device 'omapdrm'...failed                                                                                   
trying to open device 'exynos'...failed                                                                                    
trying to open device 'tilcdc'...failed                                                                                    
trying to open device 'msm'...failed                                                                                       
trying to open device 'sti'...failed                                                                                       
trying to open device 'tegra'...failed                                                                                     
trying to open device 'imx-drm'...failed                                                                                   
trying to open device 'rockchip'...failed                                                                                  
trying to open device 'atmel-hlcdc'...failed                                                                               
trying to open device 'fsl-dcu-drm'...failed                                                                               
trying to open device 'vc4'...done                                                                                         
Connectors:                                                                                                                
id      encoder status          name            size (mm)       modes   encoders                                           
32      0       disconnected    HDMI-A-1        0x0             0       31                                                 
  props:                                                                                                                   
        1 EDID:                                                                                                            
                flags: immutable blob                                                                                      
                blobs:                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                           
                value:                                                                                                     
        2 DPMS:                                                                                                            
                flags: enum                                                                                                
                enums: On=0 Standby=1 Suspend=2 Off=3                                                                      
                value: 3                                                                                                   
        5 link-status:                                                                                                     
                flags: enum                                                                                                
                enums: Good=0 Bad=1                                                                                        
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        6 non-desktop:                                                                                                     
                flags: immutable range                                                                                     
                values: 0 1                                                                                                
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        4 TILE:                                                                                                            
                flags: immutable blob                                                                                      
                blobs:                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                           
                value:                                                                                                     
        37 Colorspace:                                                                                                     
                flags: enum                                                                                                
                enums: Default=0 SMPTE_170M_YCC=1 BT709_YCC=2 XVYCC_601=3 XVYCC_709=4 SYCC_601=5 opYCC_601=6 opRGB=7 BT2020
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        33 left margin:                                                                                                    
                flags: range                                                                                               
                values: 0 100                                                                                              
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        34 right margin:                                                                                                   
                flags: range                                                                                               
                values: 0 100                                                                                              
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        35 top margin:                                                                                                     
                flags: range                                                                                               
                values: 0 100                                                                                              
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        36 bottom margin:                                                                                                  
                flags: range                                                                                               
                values: 0 100                                                                                              
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        38 max bpc:                                                                                                        
                flags: range                                                                                               
                values: 8 12                                                                                               
                value: 8                                                                                                   
        7 HDR_OUTPUT_METADATA:                                                                                             
                flags: blob                                                                                                
                blobs:                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                           
                value:                                                                                                     
        39 Broadcast RGB:                                                                                                  
                flags: enum                                                                                                
                enums: Automatic=0 Full=1 Limited 16:235=2                                                                 
                value: 0                                                                                                   
41      40      connected       HDMI-A-2        1600x900                38      40                                         
  modes:                                                                                                                   
        index name refresh (Hz) hdisp hss hse htot vdisp vss vse vtot                                                      
  #0 3840x2160 30.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 297000 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: preferred, driver         
  #1 4096x2160 30.00 4096 4184 4272 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 297000 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #2 4096x2160 29.97 4096 4184 4272 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 296703 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #3 4096x2160 25.00 4096 5064 5152 5280 2160 2168 2178 2250 297000 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #4 4096x2160 24.00 4096 5116 5204 5500 2160 2168 2178 2250 297000 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #5 4096x2160 23.98 4096 5116 5204 5500 2160 2168 2178 2250 296703 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #6 3840x2160 29.97 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 296703 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #7 3840x2160 25.00 3840 4896 4984 5280 2160 2168 2178 2250 297000 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #8 3840x2160 24.00 3840 5116 5204 5500 2160 2168 2178 2250 297000 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #9 3840x2160 23.98 3840 5116 5204 5500 2160 2168 2178 2250 296703 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #10 1920x1080 120.00 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 297000 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                  
  #11 1920x1080 119.88 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 296703 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                  
  #12 1920x1080 100.00 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 297000 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                  
  #13 1920x1080 60.00 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 148500 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                   
  #14 1920x1080 59.94 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 148352 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                   
  #15 1920x1080i 30.00 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1094 1125 74250 flags: phsync, pvsync, interlace; type: driver        
  #16 1920x1080i 29.97 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1094 1125 74176 flags: phsync, pvsync, interlace; type: driver        
  #17 1920x1080 50.00 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 148500 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                   
  #18 1920x1080i 25.00 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1094 1125 74250 flags: phsync, pvsync, interlace; type: driver        
  #19 1920x1080 30.00 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 74250 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #20 1920x1080 29.97 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 74176 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #21 1920x1080 25.00 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 74250 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #22 1920x1080 24.00 1920 2558 2602 2750 1080 1084 1089 1125 74250 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #23 1920x1080 23.98 1920 2558 2602 2750 1080 1084 1089 1125 74176 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                    
  #24 1280x1024 60.02 1280 1328 1440 1688 1024 1025 1028 1066 108000 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                   
  #25 1360x768 60.02 1360 1424 1536 1792 768 771 777 795 85500 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                         
  #26 1280x720 60.00 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 74250 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                         
  #27 1280x720 59.94 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 74176 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                         
  #28 1280x720 50.00 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 74250 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                         
  #29 1024x768 60.00 1024 1048 1184 1344 768 771 777 806 65000 flags: nhsync, nvsync; type: driver                         
  #30 800x600 60.32 800 840 968 1056 600 601 605 628 40000 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver                             
  #31 720x576 50.00 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 27000 flags: nhsync, nvsync; type: driver                              
  #32 720x576i 25.00 720 732 795 864 576 580 586 625 13500 flags: nhsync, nvsync, interlace, dblclk; type: driver          
  #33 720x480 60.00 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 27027 flags: nhsync, nvsync; type: driver                              
  #34 720x480 59.94 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 27000 flags: nhsync, nvsync; type: driver                              
  #35 640x480 60.00 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 25200 flags: nhsync, nvsync; type: driver                              
  #36 640x480 59.94 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 25175 flags: nhsync, nvsync; type: driver                              
  #37 720x400 70.08 720 738 846 900 400 412 414 449 28320 flags: nhsync, pvsync; type: driver                              
  props:                                                                                                                   
        1 EDID:                                                                                                            
                flags: immutable blob                                                                                      
                blobs:                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                           
                value:                                                                                                     
                        00ffffffffffff001e6dc8c001010101                                                                   
                        011f010380a05a780aee91a3544c9926                                                                   
                        0f5054a1080031404540614071408180                                                                   
                        d1c00101010104740030f2705a80b058                                                                   
                        8a0040846300001e023a801871382d40                                                                   
                        582c450040846300001e000000fd0018                                                                   
                        781e871e000a202020202020000000fc                                                                   
                        004c472054562053534352320a200136                                                                   
                        020354f1565f101f0413051403021220                                                                   
                        212215015d5e6263643f402c09570715                                                                   
                        07505707016704036e030c001000b83c                                                                   
                        2c008001020304e200cfe305c000e50e                                                                   
                        60616566eb0146d000480376825e6d95                                                                   
                        e3060d01662150b051001b3040703600                                                                   
                        40846300001e00000000000000000000                                                                   
                        000000000000000000000000000000ea                                                                   
        2 DPMS:                                                                                                            
                flags: enum                                                                                                
                enums: On=0 Standby=1 Suspend=2 Off=3                                                                      
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        5 link-status:                                                                                                     
                flags: enum                                                                                                
                enums: Good=0 Bad=1                                                                                        
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        6 non-desktop:                                                                                                     
                flags: immutable range                                                                                     
                values: 0 1                                                                                                
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        4 TILE:                                                                                                            
                flags: immutable blob                                                                                      
                blobs:                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                           
                value:                                                                                                     
        42 Colorspace:                                                                                                     
                flags: enum                                                                                                
                enums: Default=0 SMPTE_170M_YCC=1 BT709_YCC=2 XVYCC_601=3 XVYCC_709=4 SYCC_601=5 opYCC_601=6 opRGB=7 BT2020
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        33 left margin:                                                                                                    
                flags: range                                                                                               
                values: 0 100                                                                                              
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        34 right margin:                                                                                                   
                flags: range                                                                                               
                values: 0 100                                                                                              
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        35 top margin:                                                                                                     
                flags: range                                                                                               
                values: 0 100                                                                                              
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        36 bottom margin:                                                                                                  
                flags: range                                                                                               
                values: 0 100                                                                                              
                value: 0                                                                                                   
        43 max bpc:                                                                                                        
                flags: range                                                                                               
                values: 8 12                                                                                               
                value: 8                                                                                                   
        7 HDR_OUTPUT_METADATA:                                                                                             
                flags: blob                                                                                                
                blobs:                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                           
                value:                                                                                                     
        44 Broadcast RGB:                                                                                                  
                flags: enum                                                                                                
                enums: Automatic=0 Full=1 Limited 16:235=2                                                                 
                value: 0
```

Which refers to the HDMI outputs differently, I'm assuming `HDMI-A-1` maps to `vc4-HDMI-0` in VLC player, and `HDMI-A-2` maps to `vc4-HDMI-1` in VLC Player.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So, my settings above set the default output for the ALSA audio output.
Once that is done, I needed to select ALSA from the Audio output settings, instead of the default "Automatic" setting.
That fixed the issue.